# How are images in imap mails supposed to be stored?

Tags: dovecot, imap

On a mail server running postfix and dovecot with imap, mails are stored plain on the disk. Within those mails, we have discovered that mails are stored in 2 ways.

1. The image is embedded as a base64 code block
2. The image is linked via an url such as `imap://user@example.com/inboxname`

Which one is the correct way to store those images? Is there a standard to follow?

I am asking because the second way causes severe issues with our mail client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The image is embedded as a base64 code block

This is the current standard way to actually store an image within an email.

You should read about [Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, or MIME for short.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)

> 2. The image is linked via an url such as `imap://user@example.com/inboxname`

This is not so much storing an image as linking (i.e. *referring to*) some content in another email message. In principle, any applicable type of URL could be used for that.

But using an `imap:` URL only works if the recipient of the message can have access to the mailbox the URL refers to. It might be a viable strategy for deduplication of content within a single organization where all the users can be authenticated in a mutually trustworthy way and can give each other permissions to access the content. But in a wider scale, between different organizations, this is unlikely to be reliable or even feasible.

I think having a mail client follow random `imap:` URLs is **not a good idea**. Linking to an IMAP mailbox with hostile content might trick the mail client into bypassing some anti-malware and/or anti-spam protections. If a link points to a mailbox that is under someone else's control, it means that someone may be able to modify the linked content at will, which might allow some types of mail fraud or other deceptive practices.

And even the attempt to access the linked document (using any URL scheme at all) indicates that a particular email is being read... if those links are individualized, it might lead into an information disclosure, allowing the administrator of the link destination to determine which email recipients exist in your organization, which could be a privacy issue, and may be preparation for further social engineering attacks.

In email, many things are technically possible, but not necessarily good things to actually do.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I am asking because we are running into a 16 year old Thunderbird bug (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216308) at work and the imap:// links are causing it. That is why I wanted to know how it is supposed to be stored, now I need to find out what is causing the imap:// links.